# Posting large number of messages to AMQP queue

Tags: ruby, amqp, eventmachine

Using v0.7.1 of the Ruby amqp library and Ruby 1.8.7, I am trying to post a large number (millions) of short (~40 bytes) messages to a RabbitMQ server. My program's main loop (well, not really a loop, but still) looks like this:

```ruby
AMQP.start(:host => '1.2.3.4', 
       :username => 'foo',
       :password => 'bar') do |connection|

  channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  exchange = channel.topic("foobar", {:durable => true})
  i = 0

  EM.add_periodic_timer(1) do
    print "\rPublished #{i} commits"
  end

  results = get_results # <- Returns an array 

  processor = proc do
    if x = results.shift then
        exchange.publish(x, :persistent => true, 
                         :routing_key => "test.#{i}")
        i += 1
        EM.next_tick processor
      end
  end
  EM.next_tick(processor)
  AMQP.stop {EM.stop} end
```

The code starts processing the results array just fine, but after a while (usually, after 12k messages or so) it dies with the following error

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/amqp-0.7.1/lib/amqp/channel.rb:807:in `send': 
The channel 1 was closed, you can't use it anymore! (AMQP::ChannelClosedError)
```

No messages are stored on the queue. The error seems to be happening just when network activity from the program to the queue server starts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the RabbitMQ log say? Is the broker still running? What does `lsof -i :5672` return?

Comment: Nothing special, it says that a connection is opened when the script starts then it is closed. RabbitMQ continues to be working normally serving other queues and clients even after my code fails. I do not think this is a problem with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score -1):

First mistake is that you didn't post the RabbitMQ version that you are using. Lots of people are running old obsolete version 1.7.2 because that is what is in their OS package repositories. Bad move for anyone sending the volume of messages that you are. Get RabbitMQ 2.5.1 from the RabbitMQ site itself and get rid of your default system package.

Second mistake is that you did not tell us what is in the RabbitMQ logs.

Third mistake is that you said nothing about what is consuming the messages. Is there another process running somewhere that has declared a queue and bound it to the exchange. There is *NO* message queue unless somebody declares it to RabbitMQ and binds it to an exchange. Even then messages will only flow if the binding key for the queue matches the routing key that you publish with.

Fourth mistake. You have routing keys and binding keys mixed up. The routing key is a string such as topic.test.json.echos and the binding key (used to bind a queue to an exchange) is a pattern like topic.# or topic.*.json.*

*Updated after your clarifications*
Regarding versions, I'm not sure when it was fixed but there was a problem in 1.7.2 with large numbers of persistent messages causing RabbitMQ to crash when it rolled over its persistence log, and after crashing it was unable to restart until someone manually undid the rollover.

When you say that a connection is being opened and closed, I hope that it is not per message. That would be a strange way to use AMQP.

Let me repeat. Producers do *NOT* write messages to queues. They write messages to exchanges which then route the messages to queues based on the routing key (string) and the queue's binding key (pattern). In your example I misread the use of the # sign, but I see nothing which declares a queue and binds it to the exchange.

Comment: Let me clarify: 1. Indeed, I am using Debian's default version (1.8.1). Using Python's AMQP lib, this version can endure 10thns of millions of messages without breaking a sweat. 2. Nothing special, except that a connection is opened, then closed. 3. There are several consumers declaring the appropriate queue bindings (verified working). However, consumers should not affect the producer's capability of writing messages to the queue. 4. No, this is not a queue binding, this is Ruby's way of in place string substitution.

Comment: In all, I believe it is a Ruby AMQP/eventmachine bug and not a bug in my code or RabbitMQ. The whole setup is working properly for a small number of messages.